# Firefox extensions are broken

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-profile

Extensions are broken in Firefox on my machine. I have Windows 7 and v16.0.2 of Firefox.

I'm having the following symptoms:

- I'm able to install extensions normally. However, they do not take effect (don't show up in menus, context menus, or run). This is true for *all* extensions.
- In the Add-ons Manager, when I click "Options" for an installed and enabled extension, the entire browser freezes and only killing the process exits the program
- When I restart the browser I get a tab for each installed extension with the text "Another program on your computer would like to modify Firefox with the following add-on:"
- There is never an extensions.sqlite file in my Profile (!)
- When I check "Allow this installation" and press "Continue" the extension appears enabled
- Even upon a clean reinstallation of Firefox (even deleting all folders), the issue persists

I've tried everything under the sun and I'm completely baffled. Anyone have ideas?

---

**Solution!**

Alright thank you gentlemen, the combination of your advice fixed the issue. Certain files were not given permission to my profile folder. For reference, here's the logs:

- [image1](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3cTiZ4PA_UIVFcxRjV6MG8zVmc)
- [image2](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3cTiZ4PA_UIbm5wTXUxRHpUX00)

The addons list was always being rebuilt since there was an NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED error when calling XPIDB_writeAddonsList and XPIDB_openDatabaseFile. Then I guess it failed.

The solution was to create a new profile in a subfolder of my Users folder, where apparently there are no permission issues.

I imagine this is the result of some lovely corporate security policy gone haywire.

(edit: also posted as Answer below)

Comment: Yes, no `extensions.sqlite` sounds like something that would cause such issues. No idea about the root cause however. How about going to `about:config` and changing `extensions.logging.enabled` preference to `true`? The Add-ons Manager will log some additional information to the Error Console (press Ctrl-Shift-J to open it) next time you try to install an extension - it might explain what is going wrong.

Comment: Hey Blake, why not post your solution as an answer instead of editing it into the question?  It's allowed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a new Firefox profile and see if the issue persists? For creating a new profile, open command promptaCan you create a new Firefox profile and see if the issue persists? For creating a new profile

1. Close existing instances of Firefox.
2. Open command prompt and type: "c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -p
3. Click on **Create Profile...**
4. Select a profile name, press **Next** and press **Start Firefox**.

Incase this does not fix your issue and you want to go back to your default profile, just follow the above steps till step 2 and select **Default** and click **Ok**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution!**

Alright thank you gentlemen, the combination of your advice fixed the issue. Certain files were not given permission to my profile folder. For reference, here's the logs:

- [image1](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3cTiZ4PA_UIVFcxRjV6MG8zVmc)
- [image2](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3cTiZ4PA_UIbm5wTXUxRHpUX00)

The addons list was always being rebuilt since there was an NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED error when calling XPIDB_writeAddonsList and XPIDB_openDatabaseFile. Then I guess it failed.

The solution was to create a new profile in a subfolder of my Users folder, where apparently there are no permission issues.

I imagine this is the result of some lovely corporate security policy gone haywire.